Translating For Loops into apply in R
I have been using R for years, but I don't seem to be able to get my head around writing Looped actions in the apply functions. Could someone help me finally conceptualize the logic please?
In this example, I have a nested for loop, where there are 4200 unique IDs (i) and I am trying to fill the empty data frame for 371 columns that match names between the Washu data frame and demo data set. The loop correctly takes the first observation (row) for each unique ID in demo and fills out the data frame called Washu. However, it is taking 10 minutes to run and I thought that this might be a chance to ask for help to learn how to use apply functions.
the code I used is:
washu <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(demo$id)), 
                          length(cols)))

Here cols = a vector with all column names in, including the id (index) variable and the column names match both Washu and demo dfs.
I then add the id variable that I use for referencing to the Washu def
washu$id <- unique(demo$id)

After which I run this loop
for (i in washu$id){
  for(j in cols){
    washu[,j][washu$id==i] <- demo[,j][demo$id==i & !is.na(demo[,j])][1]
    rm(j)
  }
  rm(i)
}

Any help in understanding how to translate this into an apply function would help a lot, thanks

It sounds like you want washu to be the first row per group from the demo data frame for selected columns. Both a for loop and apply are terrible ways to do this. With library(dplyr) you could do washu <- demo |> select(all_of(cols)) |> slice(1, .by = id). Or with base R you could do washu <- demo[!duplicated(demo$id), cols]. Both of these should run in less than 1 second. (Base R might get a little more complicated if the group definition needed multiple columns, but for a single column it's very simple.)

Also, as an FYI, you don't need to use rm(i) and rm(j) inside you loops.
